# python-docx how to apply different styles to different cells in a table

Tags: python, python-docx

Working on a table in python-docx. I am trying to apply a different style to the first row of the table vs. the rest of the rows. This would be the Header row. Here's the table:

```
table2 = doc.add_table(rows=10, cols=3)
heading_cells_table2 = table2.rows[0].cells 
heading_cells_table2[0].text = 'Header 1'
heading_cells_table2[1].text = 'Header 2'
heading_cells_table2[2].text = 'Header 3'
```

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
table2.rows[0].style = table_heading_style
```

I've tried a bunch of other variations and combinations of .add_run(), .cells, .font, .text, etc. with no luck.

Is it possible to change formatting for individual cells/rows/columns in a table? If so, how is it done?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT

For a specific example of the answer to this problem, here's how I ended up Centering the text in 2 out of 3 columns in a table, thanks to scanny's help.

```
for column in itertools.islice(table2.columns, 1, 3):
    for cell in column.cells:
        for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
            paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A paragraph style can only be applied to a paragraph.

```
for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
    paragraph.style = document.styles['Heading 1']
```

Comment: not following. is each paragraph an ordered list within a cell? lets use a simple case. say i have a table style where all paragraphs are BOLD face. say there is a single cell where i want the paragraph to be ITALICS instead. is that possible?

Comment: A cell contains a sequence of paragraphs in .paragraphs. Each paragraph has an optional style. To apply a style to the paragraphs in a cell you must apply a paragraph style individually to each of those paragraphs. Note that style means something specific in the context of a Word document. An individual character formatting attribute like bold or italic is something applied at the run level. There is more on styles and python-pptx here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html

Comment: ok got it. access each individual paragraph in a cell like any other list. thanks again for your help. only 7 more rep points to go and i can up vote. dare to dream!

Comment: @RyJohn In Python, there is this general notion of a `Sequence`. Basically it specifies an interface. It is a collection in which the order of items is preserved. It can be iterated (`for item in seq:`), an item accessed by index (`x_0 = xs[0]`), and it has a len (`assert len(xs) == 3`). A list is a sequence and so is a tuple. In `python-pptx`, `Paragraphs` is a sequence, but it is not a list. That doesn't matter for interface purposes because it implements the sequence interface. Subtle difference I suppose but something to pay attention to if you're planning on doing more with Python :)

Comment: great feedback. appreciate the detail. definitely important to know the difference b/w Sequence and List/Tuple/etc